# Adding Total as a new row in Select Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Please help me write a SQL query (plsql) to transform data in Screenshot_1 to Screenshot_2.

**Screenshot_1**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/66QJr.jpg)

**Screenshot_2**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujTzR.jpg)

I tried following query but didn't work.

```
with t1 as
(select complex, sum(manpower) as tot_manpower from test1_tab group by complex)
select complex, manpower from test1_tab
union all
select complex, tot_manpower from t1
```

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please read on [why using images of code/data/errors is bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Finally, if somebody answers your question and you are satisfied with it, upvote it and accept it as correct answer. Good luck with finding answers to your questions!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option; it uses `group by rollup`.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test1_tab (id, complex, division, manpower, value1, value2) as
  2    (select 1, 'Ban', 'A', 10, 0.12, 0.15 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Ban', 'B', 20, 0.11, null from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Ban', 'C', 30, null, 0.55 from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 4, 'Hel', 'D', 15, null, 0.44 from dual union all
  7     select 5, 'Hel', 'F', 25, null, null from dual union all
  8     select 6, 'Hel', 'G', 35, 0.33, 0.06 from dual union all
  9     --
 10     select 7, 'MIG', 'E', 40, 0.33, 0.45 from dual union all
 11     select 8, 'MIG', 'A', 50, null, 0.77 from dual
 12    )
```

Query:

```
 13  select
 14    case grouping_id(division) when 0 then division else complex || ' Total' end as division,
 15    sum(manpower) manpower,
 16    case grouping_id(division) when 0 then min(value1) else null end as value1,
 17    sum(value2) value2
 18  from test1_tab
 19  group by rollup (complex, division);

DIVISION    MANPOWER     VALUE1     VALUE2
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A                 10        ,12        ,15
B                 20        ,11
C                 30                   ,55
Ban Total         60                    ,7
D                 15                   ,44
F                 25
G                 35        ,33        ,06
Hel Total         75                    ,5
A                 50                   ,77
E                 40        ,33        ,45
MIG Total         90                  1,22
 Total           225                  2,42

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Your problem can also be solved using grouping sets and row_number to order properly in this way:

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT COMPLEX, DIVISION,  SUM(MANPOWER)AS MANPOWER, VALUE1, SUM(VALUE2)AS VALUE2,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY complex ORDER BY division) rn
FROM your_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((COMPLEX, DIVISION, VALUE1), (COMPLEX), ())
)
SELECT CASE WHEN DIVISION IS NULL and complex is not null THEN COMPLEX || ' '|| 'Total' 
when DIVISION IS NULL and complex is  null THEN 'Total' else division end as division,
manpower, value1, value2,rn
from data;
```

I hope it helps.